# Recommended way for child-parent relationship in pytables

Tags: python, parent-child, pytables

I'm working with pytables and I'm trying to implement a parent-child relationship. For example, I want to store multiple teams, each with multiple players. I can do it in the following way:

```
import tables as tb



class Team(tb.IsDescription):
    id = tb.Int32Col() #Id of team
    name = tb.StringCol(20) #Name of team


class Player(tb.IsDescription):
    team = tb.Int32Col() #Link to team::team_id
    name = tb.StringCol(20) #Name of player

f = tb.open_file('test.h5',mode='w',title='test')
table_team = f.create_table(f.root,'teams',Team)
table_player = f.create_table(f.root,'players',Player)

team = table_team.row
team['id'] = 0
team['name'] = 'Barcelona'
team.append()

player0 = table_player.row
player0['team'] = 0
player0['name'] = 'De Jong'
player0.append()

player1 = table_player.row
player1['team'] = 0
player1['name'] = 'Fati'
player1.append()

f.close()
```

However, pytables documentation states the following about this (https://www.pytables.org/cookbook/hints_for_sql_users.html):

> "You may have noticed that queries in PyTables only cover one table.
> In fact, there is no way of directly performing a join between two
> tables in PyTables (remember that it’s not a relational database)."

It then proceeds to give some workarounds for join-queries. However, as they state, pytables is not a relational database. Therefore, instead of using the relation-based method and using workarounds, I have the following question:

**What is the recommended/standard way of implementing a parent-child structure in pytables?**

Comment: What do you need to *do* with them?

Comment: @ScottHunter For the case I'm currently working on, it is just storing values and plotting them later. Basically, the parent will be an experiment and the children will be the datapoints, which will be added periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need parent-child relationships for your use case? I think the HDF5 hierarchical data structure will organize your experimental data.  Create a different Table for each experiment, with the rows as the datapoints. Experiment metadata is stored as attributes on each table.

I created a simple example with "dummy data" to demonstrate this schema.

Note: for simplicity, I prefer to use NumPy to create the Table. First I create a datatype (`exp_dt`), then use it to create the baseline "experimental data" as a NumPy recarrry (`exp_arr`). Table data is created by modifying the time and pressure values in `exp_arr` to create a 2nd array (`data`). I load `data` into each table with the `obj=data` parameter. The example can be modified to create `class Experiment(tb.IsDescription)` and load the data row-by-row.

Code below:

```
# define table structure with NumPy dtype
exp_dt = np.dtype( [ ('Time',float),('Temp',float),('Pres',float) ] )

# create baseline dummy data (used later)
exp_arr = np.empty(shape=(11,), dtype=exp_dt)
for i in range(11):
    exp_arr[i]['Time'] = i/10.
    exp_arr[i]['Temp'] = i**2/10.
    exp_arr[i]['Pres'] = 2.*i

# create empty recarray; used to load experimental data
data = np.empty(shape=(11,), dtype=exp_dt)

# create some metadata for experiment date, time and device
date_list = ['11/17/2021','11/19/2021','11/23/2021']
time_list = ['10:49:23', '08:14:25', '14:40:23' ]
device_list = ['Hex 6500', 'Hex 4414', 'CMM 6950']
        
with tb.File('SO_70082470.h5','w') as h5f:
    for i in range(1,4):
        # create dummy data for THIS experiment
        data['Time'] = exp_arr['Time']
        data['Temp'] = exp_arr['Temp'] + i
        data['Pres'] = exp_arr['Pres'] + 2.*i
        # create table and load data
        tbl = h5f.create_table('/', f'Experiment_{i:03}', obj=data)
        # add 3 attributes: Date, Time and Device:
        tbl.attrs['Date'] = date_list[i-1]
        tbl.attrs['Time'] = time_list[i-1]
        tbl.attrs['Device'] = device_list[i-1]
```

Comment: Yes, probably I need to change my way of thinking a bit away from the relational method. Your method seems like a good way to do this. However, the only thing I'm missing is some way to store meta-data about the experiment. I could add a table 'experiments', but i'm also open to other ideas.

Comment: HDF5 (and PyTables) use attributes to store metadata. Attributes/metadata can be any kind of data -- strings, integers, floats, even arrays. I modified the example above to show how to add 3 attributes.